# Numbering in next item of outer list gets confused by numbered inner list of previous item in same outer list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, documentation

I am making a document and writing the body. I have many headings like:

1 Introduction (applied heading1 style)

2 Basics (applied heading1 style)

3 Experimentation (applied heading1 style)

1 setup (applied heading2 style)

2 results (applied heading2 style)

3 graphs (applied heading2 style)

4 interpretation (applied heading2 style)

4 Conclusion (applied heading1 style)

**At Experimentation, I start an inner list of 4 items**. and then I continue with next item in outer list, Next item is Conclusion. I want Conclusion to be numbered 4, but by default it continues from inner list of Experimentation and takes the number 5. I can manually change it to 4 by right clicking on it and "set numbering value" to 4. **But problem with this is that**, if I insert an item between Basics and Experimentation, then in continuation, I would like Conclusion to be numbered as 5, but since earlier I had hard-coded the Conclusion number as 4, it remains the same. How to do it, so that number is Conclusion gets auto-adjusted.

Is there any other way to solve the mentioned problem? Perhaps word could detect which list numbering I want to continue based on style which I have applied on the text or something totally different solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did the above numbering on my Word 2007 and it worked!

The point is, don't right click on `b` but right click on the number before `b` (i.e. `2)`)

The option `Restart at 1` should appear like below:

[image: Right click on 2]

The result should be something like:

[image: Numbering restarted at 1]

---

Extra information:

Select all the content you want to put in your list, then select the indicated multilevel list from the List library as below:

[image: Select the multilevel list]

Next set the style to your text (e.g. `Heading 1` or `Heading 2` and so on) according to the level of the list you want. It will automatically do the hierarchical numbering according to the Heading level selected, like below:

[image: Select the heading level]

If you want to personalize the numbering format just click on `Define New Multilevel List`:

[image: New Multilevel List]

Then you can edit the multilevel properties according to your "taste" and you won't need to use the Tab thing.

---

**Optional:**
To set alignment and hierarchical numbering just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the `b1`, for instance, to put it within list of `b` and the hierarchical numbering will be changed automatically if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again it will go to a lower level of list.

To come back to a higher level of list just hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

**Note:** To use this <kbd>Tab</kbd> feature the cursor must be at the beginning of the line (i.e. before `b1` or `b2`, etc).

Comment: Thanks yes. A few more questions: How do I make the inner list start on inner alignment than heading 1 lists.I chose heading 2 style for inner list, but the text starts from the same alignment. What is the style for shifted alignment in list? Also how do I have hierarchical numbering, so list within 2) b should be called as 2.1) and 2.2)

Comment: @learnerforever: look at the Extra information.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. tab thing works. I still have a question on I can't get hierarchical numbers for inner list. Please look in **addition** of my question.

Comment: @learnerforever: I have edited my answer, and now I think that if you follow the steps on "Extra information" you will have the numbering expected.

Comment: THANKS!! It works. Thanks again for the detailed answer.