# Sub numbered list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I found it very difficult to create sub-numbered list in Microsoft Word 2016.

Say I want to make a numbered list and in couple of them to create a sub list something like that:

```
1. ...
2. a. ...
   b.  
       Sub numbered list:
       1. Item 1.
       2. Item 2.
3. Sub numbered list:
   1. Item 1.
   2. Item 2.
....
```

When I try to do that, the main numbered list changes or the sub-numbered list acts like it continue the main numbered list numbers.

Is there easy way to create sub numbered list without changing the main numbered list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numbering in next item of outer list gets confused by numbered inner list of previous item in same outer list](http://superuser.com/questions/246933/numbering-in-next-item-of-outer-list-gets-confused-by-numbered-inner-list-of-pre)

Comment: It is not solving my problem.. When I "Restart at 1", its effects my main list too...